# place iframe at specific point in HTML page's body?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-chrome

I've got the following..

```
var insertbeforenode = document.body;


var outerdiv = doc.createElement('div');
outerdiv.id = '_dialog_div';
outerdiv.style.display = "none"; 

var overlay = doc.createElement("link");
overlay.href = chrome.extension.getURL("overlay.css");
overlay.rel = "stylesheet";
overlay.type = "text/css";
outerdiv.appendChild(overlay);

var iFrame = doc.createElement('iframe');
iFrame.id = '_dialog_iframe';
iFrame.name = '_dialog_iframe';

outerdiv.appendChild(iFrame);
doc.body.appendChild(outerdiv);
```

However, as expected it appends the `outerdiv` to the bottom of the page which isn't what I want to do. I'd like to insert it before `insertbeforenode`. I've tried `insertbeforenode.parentNode.insertBefore(outerdiv, insertbeforenode);` but that doesn't appear to work in Chrome. Does anyone have any solutions?

**EDIT:** Just to clarify the effect I'm looking to create is..

```
<html>
  <head></head>
    <iframe here> </iframe here>
  <body> </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If I'm reading this right, you're trying to insert it *before* `<body>`? Are you sure that's what you're after?

Comment: Yes, doing this produces the effect I'm looking to achieve in Firefox but for some reason doing the `insertbeforenode.parentNode.insertBefore(outerdiv, insertbeforenode);` in Chrome doesn't work.

Comment: @Skizit Only HEAD and BODY is valid inside the HTML element - what you are trying to do is not standardized. You should seriously reconsider your approach.

Comment: @Sean I realise this but I'm looking to recreate an effect which was done in Firefox for Chrome.

Comment: @Skizit And what is this effect?? And how can it not be accomplished within the body?

Comment: @Sean I'm looking to place the iframe like a popup over the window with some div's inside it (Without it actually being a popup

Comment: @Skizit ... okay, and what does this have to do with you placing it outside the body? Use css and absolute positioning like the rest of us.

Answer (score 0):

When I do this in Firefox:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <iframe> </iframe>
    <body> </body>
</html>
```

It looks the same as this:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <iframe></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

But your comments and notes indicate that you're trying to place the `iframe` over the page without altering the appearance of the underlying content.

What you really want is this structure:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <!-- Normal content goes here -->
        <iframe>
            <!-- Added iframe goes at the bottom -->
        </iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then you set `position:absolute;` on the `iframe`; give it the usual `width` and `height`; and then set `top`, `left`, and the [margins](http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html) [to](http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html) [center](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html) it. You might need to play around with `z-index` values on the `iframe` too but that depends on the page's content.

Adding an absolutely positioned element at the bottom of `<body>` is the usual of way of achieving what you're trying to do and it will work pretty much the same in any browser that can handle an `iframe`.

Here's a simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/KrjBv/. You already know how to do the JavaScript and I'm just trying to illustrate the CSS positioning so I used jQuery to cut down on the noise.